# Error indexing catalogsearch_fulltext

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, indexing

I'm using the latest version of Magento2 (`2.4.6p3`) and Elasticsearch (`7.17.14`). I don't know really why but I can't index `catalogsearch_fulltext` anymore.

I set ES as debug and the log shows this error:

```
org.elasticsearch.indices.InvalidIndexNameException: Invalid index name [_product_1_v1], must not start with '_'.
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver$WildcardExpressionResolver.validateAliasOrIndex(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:1227) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver$WildcardExpressionResolver.innerResolve(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:1165) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver$WildcardExpressionResolver.resolve(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:1144) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver.concreteIndices(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:292) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver.concreteIndexNames(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:270) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver.concreteIndexNames(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:92) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.info.TransportClusterInfoAction.checkBlock(TransportClusterInfoAction.java:53) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.info.TransportClusterInfoAction.checkBlock(TransportClusterInfoAction.java:24) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.checkBlockIfStateRecovered(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:138) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.access$000(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:52) ~[elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction.doStart(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:185) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.doExecute(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:158) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.doExecute(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:52) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:186) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.ActionFilter$Simple.apply(ActionFilter.java:53) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:184) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.action.filter.SecurityActionFilter.apply(SecurityActionFilter.java:145) [x-pack-security-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:184) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:161) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:82) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:95) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.RestCancellableNodeClient.doExecute(RestCancellableNodeClient.java:81) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:407) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1303) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.getIndex(AbstractClient.java:1399) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.admin.indices.RestGetIndicesAction.lambda$prepareRequest$1(RestGetIndicesAction.java:86) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:109) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.rest.SecurityRestFilter.handleRequest(SecurityRestFilter.java:99) [x-pack-security-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:340) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.tryAllHandlers(RestController.java:405) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:252) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(AbstractHttpServerTransport.java:384) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport.handleIncomingRequest(AbstractHttpServerTransport.java:478) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.AbstractHttpServerTransport.incomingRequest(AbstractHttpServerTransport.java:358) [elasticsearch-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(Netty4HttpRequestHandler.java:35) [transport-netty4-client-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(Netty4HttpRequestHandler.java:19) [transport-netty4-client-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpPipeliningHandler.channelRead(Netty4HttpPipeliningHandler.java:48) [transport-netty4-client-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111) [netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [netty-codec-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpHeaderValidator.forwardData(Netty4HttpHeaderValidator.java:194) [transport-netty4-client-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpHeaderValidator.forwardFullRequest(Netty4HttpHeaderValidator.java:137) [transport-netty4-client-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpHeaderValidator.lambda$requestStart$1(Netty4HttpHeaderValidator.java:120) [transport-netty4-client-7.17.14.jar:7.17.14]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) [netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.run(PromiseTask.java:106) [netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) [netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) [netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) [netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:566) [netty-transport-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) [netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.94.Final.jar:4.1.94.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) [?:?]
```

I tried to set a prefix but seems not apply before and it still starts with `_`. Same with `7.17.0` for ES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using OpenSearch for testing and doesn't have the issue with this index name thing.

Deploy again our Magento seems to fix the issue and add correctly back the prefix for the index. Maybe related with an extension or database value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

```
indices.id_field_data.enabled: true
```

in your elasticsearch.yml?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! I didn't have it.
But no really sure neither, the issue was solved after deploy again the website. I did test with OpenSearch and was working fine with the previous index. Seems a configuration error because of the prefix some how.